# devise admin user approval setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Seems like the tutorial located [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in) has a couple omissions:

1. When creating the admin accessible controller method, they don't specify *which* custom devise controller to use, or which base controller to inherit from. So I've placed my code in a PagesController:

   ```
   class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def approve_users
     if current_user.admin?
      if params[:approved] == "false"
       @users = User.find_by_approved(false)
      else
       @users = User.all
      end
     end
    end
   end
   ```
2. The view code that allows you to switch between all users and all unapproved users results in a `NoMethodError in Pages@approve_users`: `undefined method 'each' for User` whenever you select to show the users for whom `:approved => false`. I know why noMethodErrors spring up in app development, and would normally be able to wrap my head around why I'm getting this error. It *works* when `@users = User.all`, but not when `@users = User.find_by_approved(false)`

   ```
   <% if current_user.admin? %>
    <h2>Users</h2>
    <%= link_to "All Users", :action => "approve_users" %> | <%= link_to "Users awaiting approval", :action => "approve_users", :approved => "false" %>
    <div class="ui form">
     <table>
      <thead>
       <tr scope="col">
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>Approve</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <% @users.each do |user| %>
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td><%= user.firstname %></td>
         <td><%= user.lastname %></td>
         <td><%= user.email %></td>
         <td class="ui checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="hidden">
         </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      <% end %>
     </table>
    </div>
   <% end %>
   ```

   3. The wiki says it that it provides a simple way to approve users, but their view code actually just provides a simple way to *list* all users. I'm assuming that I need to use a form helper.

Answer (score 0):

1. I made a custom admin controller specifically for an admin control panel and put all of the tools in an index page. You can probably do it a number of ways, though.
2. The common consensus on this seems to be that if you switch @users = User.find_by_approved(false) to @users = User.where(approved: false), it works better. That's what I currently have and it works very well.
3. I had this problem as well, and I ended up scrapping devise and making a custom user sign in method. You should be able to make it work, though. I followed the tutorial [here](https://rubyplus.com/articles/3491) and it helped immensely. Basically, you want to create a method which will approve users in your admin controller. This is the one I used:

`

```
def approve
User.where(id: params[:user_id]).update_all(approved: true)

  redirect_to admin_index_path
end
```

From there, you add a put method to your routes.

```
put 'approve_admin', to: "admin#approve", as: :approve_admin
```

Finally, wrap your list of users in a form tag and add a hash of all of the user IDs you want to update as a hash.

```
<%= form_tag(approve_admin_path, method: :put) do %>
   <% for user in @unapproved_users %>
     <tr>
       <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><%= check_box_tag "user_id[]", user.id %></td>
       <td><%= user.name %></td>
       <td><%= user.email %></td>
       </tr>
       <% end %>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      <%= submit_tag "Mark as approved", class: 'mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised approve' %>
   <% end %>
```

I made a method for approving users and another for unapproving users so I switched up the @users.each iteration in favor of a for iteration. I added @unapproved_users to my index method to make this work properly. Hope this works for you!